# Angular - Remove label in mat-tab

Tags: html, angular

I have a form consisting of two tabs.
Based on an *ngIf, I decide what kind of tabs I want to show.
- If my form is a view, I want to see both tabs with labels (both tabs have information to show the user, second tab is results).
- If my form is an add, I want to see no tabs thus no labels.

I am not willing to create two separate files as I am trying to reduce my code as much as possible.

I tried adding an ng-template that replaces the mat-tab-label, but instead of removing it, my label is empty.

[image: Example of an empty label]

So far, this is what I have. My question would be: is it possible to remove the whole tab label without creating a new file and if yes, how can I?

```
<mat-dialog-content class="ManageTask">
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
        <mat-tab>
            <ng-template *ngIf="isView()" mat-tab-label>Task details</ng-template>
            <div class="left">
                <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['name'].hasError('required')">Name required</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
                <br/>
                <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                    <textarea matInput type="text" placeholder="Description" formControlName="description"></textarea>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['description'].hasError('required')">Description required</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab *ngIf="isView()" label="Task results">
            <div>...MORE CONTENT...</div>
        </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question.certainly you can do it.the correct way to use `<ng-template>`and`ngIf` like this:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="isView()">
    <mat-tab label="Task details">...</mat-tab>
</ng-template>
```

or :

`<mat-tab *ngIf="isView()" label="Task details">...</mat-tab>`

differences between `[ngif]` and `*ngif`:[Angular Structural Directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)

hopes it help

Comment: I re-used your idea of ng-templates and I am currently trying to fix it using a ng-container. I keep you posted.